# Best practice for passing data between dashboard components?

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2, angular8

trying to develop a web application as a passion project. I am also using Firebase (Firestore) as the back-end with angular material up front.

Right now I am nesting a bunch of components on the first dashboard of the ui. Basic things like friend requests, friend chat, game rooms. However I am finding that I am instantiating the user.uid a lot in all of the components. Right now I am passing it along just using my authService.getUser() function. However, I am concerned that because of the current way I am building this dashboard that in one login I may be reading back to Firebase some 7 or 8 times just to bring all of the different components up.

Is there a better way? I am still trying to wrap my brain around the @Input and @Output pieces of Angular as a means to pass the data. But I guess in my brain I feel like since the dashboard has all of the components I should be able to just grab the user once and pass it around freely.

Am I wrong?

Thanks much all. I can certainly share code if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use services, instead of @Input and @Output. You won't be able move the components around , if you change the design. Keep the state of the component in a service. Use can use Subject as a alternative for @Output